# Test always passing with Sinon and Chai

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I am using Mocha, Chai and Sinon to test some Node methods.

This test passes and when I change 'calledOnce' to 'calledTwice' it fails as expected.

```
 it('should call checkIfRoomExists once', function (done) {
            var check = sandbox.spy(RoomInfoModel, 'checkIfRoomExists');
            ViewBusiness.getViewToRender("thisisanoneknownroom", function (viewName) {
                expect(check.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
                done();
            })
        });
```

However when I try and follow tutorials the 'expect' is set up like this:

```
it('should call checkIfRoomExists once', function (done) {
        var check = sandbox.spy(RoomInfoModel, 'checkIfRoomExists');
        ViewBusiness.getViewToRender("thisisanoneknownroom", function (viewName) {
            expect(check).to.have.been.calledTwice;
            done();
        })
    });
```

Note that I am testing for 'calledTwice' in the second test. It still passes. If I change it to 'notCalled' it still passes. Basically it always passes.

What am I missing?

Comment: I should add, it's not to do with the tests changing state. I have been replacing one with the other and tearing down the sandbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I can reproduce the behavior you report is if I forget to call `chai.use` to add Sinon's assertions to it. For instance, this works as expected (the test fails):

```
const sinon = require("sinon");
const chai = require("chai");
const sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
chai.use(sinonChai); // This is crucial to get Sinon's assertions.
const expect = chai.expect;

it("test", () => {
    const stub = sinon.stub();
    stub();
    expect(stub).to.have.been.calledTwice;
});
```

But if you take the same code and comment out `chai.use(sinonChai)`, then the test will pass!

---

For fun, you can try `expect(stub).to.have.been.platypus` and that will pass too. Chai's `expect` interface tolerates nonsensical identifiers.

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it! Not sure what I think of having tests pass because of a typo in the expect statement though.

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem. I use Chai a lot but I never use the `should` interface and only very rarely use the `expect` interface. I use it when I contribute to third party code that already uses it. For my own code, I use the `assert` interface. It does not try to do any magic with properties so it fails **hard** if use the wrong method name.